# fopen file from same directory in c language without using the full path

Tags: c, xcode, file, directory, fopen

I'm trying to do the following:

```
FILE *fileNAME = fopen("file.txt", "r");
```

It works when I have:

```
FILE *fileNAME = fopen("users/username/desktop/folder/file.txt", "r");
```

but as I want to use this file outside my home computer the path should be relative, especially for an end user who has no access to the actual source code. My question is, how to actually make this work and if the issue is due to the compiler not using the right directory by default, how do I change that? (I am using XCODE)

Comment: None of these are absolute paths.

Comment: feel free to edit the question for technicalities, however the issue remains... could you help me out?

Comment: @user1883003 this is not even a proper question, we can't edit for 'technicalities' ( coz really, you're asking a favor here, thats your job ) without the proper information. What you're using xcode? what does that even REMOTELY have anything to do with your problem? What libraries are you using? Opensource cross platform C command line tool? Information please.

Comment: I am using #include <stdio.h>, #include <string.h>, #include <stdlib.h>. I edited to full path if that helps, and I am using the latest version of xcode with its own compiler, its own command window and lldb.

Comment: @user1883003 on *nix type systems (which is a safe assumption if you're using XCode), a full path _always_ starts with "/". Regardless of that "technicality" (welcome to programming, be precise or be somewhere else), what error are you getting, and does "file.txt" exist in your current directory? If it exists _and_ if you have read permission on the file, your relative path call as shown will succeed.

Comment: I have tried "/file.txt", "file.txt", "../file.txt", "/folderContainingFile/file.txt" and "../folderContainingFile/file.txt" but nothing works. The file does exist, it is placed in the same folder on my desktop as the .c file.

Comment: You don't need to have file located where your C file is, but where your current directory path is (it can be different than actual executable directory, so you need to call chdir to set it.)

Answer (score 2):

you can pass the file path as input argument when you call your program via command

```
$myprogram users/username/desktop/folder/file.txt
```

and in your code source you can get this path from argv

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   char *file_path = argv[1];
   ....
}
```

The argc is the length of the argv array. so if the array length is lower than 2 than your program should return help message to indicate to the user to input the file path as argument

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   char *file_path;
   if (argc <2) {
      printf("Usage: %s <file path>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }
   file_path = argv[1];
   ....
}
```

Comment: Indeed, the argc is the length of the argv array. so if the array length is lower than 2 than your program should return help message to indicate to the user to input the file path as argument. Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mac OS X (Xcode, right, I am not OS X user, but I assume this is it?), you can get current executable path (not the current working directory path) with

```
char path[1024];
uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) == 0)
    printf("executable path is %s\n", path);
else
    printf("buffer too small; need size %u\n", size);
```

After this, you have two ways:

1) Either update combine file paths with exe directory (like `sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", path, "file.txt");`)

2) Change current directory with [chdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) function and access files with relative path.

Edit: _NSGetExecutablePath returns executable path, not executable directory, so use `substr`/`strrchr`to extract path prior to the last occurence of '/' character.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I tried it and I receive a really long path name: /users/username/library/developer/xcode/deriveddata/filename-laksdjlakdsjl(actual gibberish)/build/products/debug/filename

Comment: And that is where your program is located (try to find this directory in Finder). Move program to your desktop, and start it from Terminal, it should point to your Desktop folder.

Comment: Actually it is your working space. You can edit it your current directory under Product->Scheme->edit Scheme